# Fetch as Google returns blank page with error unexpected token =>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel-polyfill, google-search-console

I'm currently working on a SPA React app, but when I try to fetch as google I get a blank page with the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>`. I did install babel-polyfill and also imported it as first import. I've been reading and trying multiple things but I can't seem to fix it, anyone experience with this?

The site is https://sharetune.nl

The error image is shown below:

[image: error]

Edit: I tried to fetch as google while my app.js wasn't minified. the error is in this piece of code

```
const prefix = (items) => {
  const result = {}
  for (const i in items) {
    result[items[i]] = swalPrefix + items[i]
  }
  return result
}
```

You can view the app.js file at http://sharetune.nl/js/app.js

Comment: can you add the code where this is breaking?

Comment: @jsdeveloper Thanks for your reply, I added the code where it is breaking.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Googlebot uses Chrome 41. You have to transpile with babel, not just include polyfills.

Comment: @destoryer That makes sense, do u know by any chance a simple guide on how to transpile with babel & react?

Comment: The official [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage) should cover your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As you say above, the google fetch bot uses Chrome 41 - which does not support arrow functions.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: I'm running version 73.0.3683.75 of Chrome so I don't think this is the problem, when fetching as google I don't think my own browser is being used to render the page.